# When $N \to M \otimes_R N$ is not an embedding.

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Can someone please provide an example of the following (or tell me why such an example doesn't exist): Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring, $M$ an $R$-$R$-bimodule containing a copy of $R$, and $N$ a left submodule of $M$, such that the map
$$
N \to M \otimes_R N, ~~~~~~ n \mapsto 1 \otimes n, 
$$
is not an embedding.

Comment: What is $1\in M$ if $M$ is just a module?

Comment: Sorry about that, should make sense now!

Comment: So to be completely clear, there's an injective $R$-$R$-bimodule morphism $R \to M$, and $1 \in M$ is the image of the unit of $R$?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: $N$ should be a left (sub)module so that the $ - \otimes_R N$ makes sense.

Comment: @Martin Thank you. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $N= \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with inclusion $R\to M:n\mapsto (n,\overline{0})$.  Then, in $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$, we have that
$$ (1,\overline{0})\otimes \overline{1} = (\frac{1}{2},\overline{0})\otimes 2\cdot\overline{1} = (\frac{1}{2},\overline{0})\otimes \overline{0} = 0.$$

Therefore the map $N\to M\otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$ described in the question is the zero map, and is not injective.